# Running a full node on Tails

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, daemon, tor

So I'm running the Monero GUI on Tails, using remote nodes, and the remote nodes are very unreliable. I was thinking about running a local node. I've read the [sheep's noob guide](https://medium.com/@Electricsheep56/sheeps-noob-guide-to-monero-gui-in-tails-3-2-d75c4e829c17) but I'm hesitant to mess with IP tables and torsocks. Is this safe and necessary to do on Tails?

If you go into the GUI where it says local node you can specify where you want to download the blockchain.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is no avoiding editing the firewall rules on Tails. Instructions for running Monero on Tails can be found in the projects [README](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/#using-tor-on-tails) and quoted below:

> ### Using Tor on Tails
>
> TAILS ships with a very restrictive set of firewall rules. Therefore,
>   you need to add a rule to allow this connection too, in addition to
>   telling torsocks to allow inbound connections. Full example:
>
> ```
> sudo iptables -I OUTPUT 2 -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 -m tcp --dport 18081 -j ACCEPT
>
> DNS_PUBLIC=tcp torsocks ./monerod --p2p-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 --no-igd --rpc-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 \
> --data-dir /home/amnesia/Persistent/your/directory/to/the/blockchain
> ```

Comment: Is it safe to change these settings though?

Comment: I see no problem with it. It wouldn't be in the Monero README if it was considered unsafe.

Comment: Does the drive need to be formatted for Linux?

Comment: If you're running on Linux, yes.

Answer (score 0):

./monero-blockchain-import --input-file /media/amnesia/PATH/TO/blockchain.raw --data-dir ~/Persistent/PATH/TO/LOCATION